# Dagger 2: injecting into provided classes

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

Having a bit of trouble understanding how Dagger works, again, this time with some code.

I have a few classes and their respective interfaces

```
public class SomeView {
    @Inject ISomeManager

    public SomeView() {}
    ...
}

public class SomeManager implements ISomeManager {
    @Inject IDataProvider

    public SomeManager() {}
    ...
}

public class DataProvider implements IDataProvider {
    ...
}
```

And a component that goes roughly like

```
@Component(modules = {DataModule.class, SomeModule.class})
public interface AppComponent() {
    ISomeView getSomeView();
}
```

So what else do I need to have to create an instance of `SomeView` via `getSomeView` with all of the injections happening correctly?

I tried to have a `@Module(includes = DataModule.class)` that `@Provides ISomeView provideISomeView()` (or, rather, `provideISomeView(IDataProvider dataProvider)` which at least does give me a correct `DataProvider` instance in said method), but no matter what I tried I couldn't get it to inject `IDataProvider` without manually setting the field in the module or even in the `SomeManager` constructor itself - which kind of makes the `@Inject` statement there kind of pointless.

Comment: can you post your Module class?

Comment: iam having fierce trouble understanding it. iam just creating a module a component and trying to inject in an activity. cant see what iam doing wrong.